# Why are the object and constructor.prototype set to Base in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Here is my little program. When I check the value of rec in the debug mode, the object is Base { x=0, y=0, w=10, more...}. Should it be Rectangle? Also the constructor.prototype is Base. Why not Shape?

```
    function Base() {
    }

    function Shape(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    Shape.prototype = new Base();
    Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
        this.x += x;
        this.y += y;
        console.log("x = " + this.x + " y = " + this.y);
    };

    function Rectangle(x, y, w, h) {
        Shape.call(this, x, y);
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
    }

    Rectangle.prototype = new Shape();
    Rectangle.prototype.area = function() {
        return this.w * this.h;
    };
    var rec = new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10);
    console.log(instanceOf(rec, Rectangle));

    function instanceOf(object, constructor) { 
        while (object != null) {
            if (object == constructor.prototype)
                return true;
            if ( typeof object == 'xml') {
                return constructor.prototype == XML.prototype;
            }
            object = object.__proto__;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Probably because `Rectangle.prototype.constructor` is `Base`.

Comment: _Also the constructor.prototype is Base._ You have to redirect the constructor like `Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle`

Comment: Note that for a native object, `typeof object == 'xml'` will never be true.

Comment: It could in Firefox 17- actually - [E4X](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/E4X)

Comment: He overwrites the `object` value in his function so it might be `XML` or any other thing.

Comment: @IanKuca—I guess you're referring to E4X. Ok, in a small number of user agents, it may be true.

Comment: @RobG: Yep, I even linked to the MDN article ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Why *[not]* to use the `new` keyword here?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12592913/1048572). You might not use it and create a new instance of it, but rather just inherit from `Base.prototype`.

> Also the constructor.prototype is Base. Why not Shape?

I'm not sure which `constructor` you are referring to here:

- The `constructor` property of all your objects is `Base`, as all of them inherit this prototype from the `Base.prototype` object. You did not overwrite it after setting up the inheritance chains. It is not really necessary, but good style: `Shape.prototype.constructor = Shape` and `Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle` - where those prototype objects are the overwritten ones which inherit from `Base`.
- The `constructor` parameter of your `instanceOf` function. You pass in `Rectangle` there, so `constructor.prototype` is the prototype object of `Rectangle`, which *inherits* from `Base` but is different.

> When I check the value of rec in the debug mode, the object is Base { x=0, y=0, w=10, more...}

Usually not. Is `Base` something special, e.g. a host object? Your `rec` object is an instance of `Base`, so it might be displayed differently because of that.

`rec` is just an object which inherits from `Rectangle.prototype` which inherits from `Shape.prototype` which inherits from `Base.prototype` which inherits from​… Assuming `Base` is the function you defined, from `Object.prototype` which inherits from `null`.

Comment: Yes, it works after adding constructors: Shape.prototype.constructor = Shape and Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle. I have one more question: why rec is a function, not an object? In the debug console, it is Function { x=

0

, y=

0

, w=

10

, more...}

Comment: One more question: after the change, rec.__proto__.property becomes an endless Rectangle chain. __proto__
 Rectangle(x, y, w, h)
 
prototype
 Rectangle(x, y, w, h)
 
prototype
 Rectangle(x, y, w, h)
 
prototype
 Rectangle(x, y, w, h)
 
prototype
 Rectangle(x, y, w, h)
 
prototype
 Rectangle(x, y, w, h)

Comment: I missed new in my constructor assignment. It works perfect now. Thanks!